# PostgreSQL, issue with joined tables

Tags: postgresql

I have issue with joined tables and need an advice how to make query according to my needs.
Here are two example tables:

**WARNING**
Be sure that you don't have your own tables named *temp1* and/or *tempclasses1* otherwise you will lose it permanently by running this example!

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 
       (food_code int, food_name text, qty integer, tclass integer, meas text);
INSERT INTO temp1 (food_code, food_name, qty, tclass, meas)
VALUES (10,  'spaghetti',        3, 1, 'pcs'),
       (156, 'mayonnaise',       2, 0, 'pcs'),
       (173, 'ketchup',          1, 2, 'pcs'),
       (172, 'bolognese sauce',  2, 1, 'pcs'),
       (173, 'ketchup',          1, 0, 'pcs'),
       (175, 'worchester sauce', 2, 3, 'pcs'),
       (177, 'parmesan',         1, 2, 'pcs'),
       (178, 'jam',              1, 4, 'pcs'),
       (10,  'spaghetti',        2, 3, 'pcs'),
       (156, 'mayonnaise',       1, 0, 'pcs');

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempclasses1;
CREATE TABLE tempclasses1 
       (class_code int, class_name text);
INSERT INTO tempclasses1 (class_code, class_name)
VALUES (1, 'first class'),
       (3, 'third class'),
       (4, 'fourth class');
```

Now I need to group and sum data from first table according to classes which is in second table.
I do this fith following query:

```
SELECT tclass, MAX(class_name), SUM(qty)
  FROM temp1 
  JOIN tempclasses1 t ON tclass=t.class_code
 GROUP BY tclass
 ORDER BY tclass;
```

... and get such result:

```
1     "first class"      5
3     "third class"      4
4     "fourth class"     1
```

Issue is with fact that I will need sum of ALL classes in result even those which are not defined in table *tempclasses1*. Like this:

```
0                        4
1     "first class"      5
2                        2
3     "third class"      4
4     "fourth class"     1
```

How would I get that with code similar to my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join):

```
SELECT 
     tclass
    ,class_name
    ,SUM(qty)
FROM temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN tempclasses1 t
  ON t1.tclass=t.class_code
GROUP BY
   tclass
  ,class_name
ORDER BY 
  tclass
;
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6c63/1).

Comment: What a trick! For whole day I wasn't be able to come to this:) Thanks!